# how do I get rid of this simple SwiftUI error?

Tags: arrays, swiftui

I just wanna get all the records from the transaction variable and save it to an array.i tried and all I am getting is this constant error. please help me, I just wanna all models(records) to be saved on an array.

*Type '()' cannot conform to 'View'*

```
   @State private var transactions: [Transactions] = [Transactions]()
   ForEach(transactions, id: \.self) { transaction in
                        timexxx[0] = transaction.timexx ?? "0"
                        Text(timexxx[0] ?? "0")

                    
                }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehcNb.png)

Comment: You can't modify variables inside view builder function. You're doing this with this line: `timexxx[0] = transaction.timexx ?? "0"`. Not sure why would you need that, if same object will be replaced each time? why not just display text? `Text(transaction.timexx ?? "0" ?? "0")`

Comment: it's a simple question. Transaction.timexx has to be saved under another array. you got it ? where do i do that ? how do i do it. ?

Comment: No, I didn't got it. How do you create `timexxx`, and how do you use it later?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like what @multiverse has suggested

> ForEach loop expects some sort of View but you are giving it or attempting to give an "array" (it only wants View)

Here is an updated code where you give the ForEach what it wants and you append to your `timexxx` array

```
ForEach(Array(transactions.enumerated()), id: \.offset) { (offset, transaction) in
              Text(transaction.timexx ?? "\(offset)")
                .onAppear {
                    timexxx[offset] = transaction.timexx ?? "\(offset)"
                }
         }
```

## Update

for your question

> "how do I do this with a simple "For" loop ? let's say I wanna do this operation in a simple class."

This is how it's done.

I removed the view `Text`.

```
for (i, transaction) in transactions.enumerated() {
    timexxx[i] = transaction.timexx ?? "0"
}
```

Comment: my question to you is that... how do I do this with a simple "For" loop ? let's say I wanna do this operation in a simple class. though.

Comment: forget the View thing.

Answer (score 0):

Ok , so this is an error i faced as well, when i was learning SwiftUI( i am still a beginner), so now we need to understand , what does this error actually means,  in this case the ForEach loop expects some sort of View but you are giving it or attempting to give an "array" (it only wants View)....

If you want values to be transferred to an array just simply create a function and do it .....

say you have a class and inside of which you do

```
@Published var song = [Song]()
```

then what you do is inside a function like loadData()

objects is the array whose elements you want transferred and most likely those elements belong to a Struct like Song here(if not its even simpler just use what ever type it has like Int, String etc.), this way all your elements will get transferred to song from objects

```
 func loadData() {
        song = objects.map {
            artist in
            Song(album: artist.album, artistImage: artist.artistImage)
        
    }
    
 }
```

Here i add the simplest possible way to transfer from one array to other

```
var objects = [1,2,3,4,5]
 var song = [Int]()
 func loadData() {
    song = objects.map { $0 }
    
 }
 
 loadData()
 print(song)



//[1,2,3,4,5]
```